# How do we perform the isomerisation of 1-butyne to 2-butyne using NaNH2?

Tags: organic-chemistry, acid-base, reaction-mechanism, isomers

How do we perform the isomerisation of 1-butyne to 2-butyne using NaNH2? As a first step, I think that $\ce{NH2^-}$ would remove $\ce{H^+}$ from the third carbon to give an allene intermediate. But I don't know how to proceed after that. Please explain the other steps.

Comment: This transformation isn't likely to happen, afaik isomerisation of alkynes with NaNH2 gives the terminal alkyne (because that can be deprotonated).

Comment: @orthocresol This is a popular question. The answer below has shown deprotonation of a non-terminal alkyne (apparently contrary to what you said "because that can be protonated"). And has an in fact converted a 2-alkyne to a 3-alkyne. Also, there's this question: [Does a non-terminal alkyne react with sodamide?](//chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/90945) So, what is correct?

Comment: @GaurangTandon answer below is wrong

Answer (score 0):

Here in the following image I have explained the mechanism for transformation of 2-alkyne to 3-alkyne. Isomerisation from 1-butyne/ 1-alkyne to 2-butyne / 2-alkyne is not possible.

[image: Mechanism]

Hope it helps.